# How to identify which IP-ranges are allowed to access an RDS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc

We have a RDS instance in one of our VPCs. We have 3 private and 3 public subnets within this VPC and the the db instance is attached to all 3 private subnets. We also have 2 separate VPCs where one is connected to the first one via site to site vpn and the other is via a peering connection.

How can I identify the IPs which are allowed to access the RDS instance?

I have to get this information using python boto3. Any idea?

Comment: Check security group of the RDS.

Answer (score 0):

Getting the exact IP-Ranges is a bit tricky, but essentially this is determined by the security groups that are assigned to the DB instance.

Here is a script that lists the inbound rules of all security groups of the DB instance "test-db":

```py
import boto3

def main():
    
    db_instance_identifier = "test-db"

    rds_client = boto3.client("rds")

    db_instances = rds_client.describe_db_instances(
        DBInstanceIdentifier=db_instance_identifier
    )

    # We expect only one result
    db_instance = db_instances["DBInstances"][0]

    # Get a list of the VPC Security Groups
    db_security_group_ids = [
        item["VpcSecurityGroupId"] for item in db_instance["VpcSecurityGroups"]
    ]

    ec2_client = boto3.client("ec2")

    security_groups = ec2_client.describe_security_groups(
        GroupIds=db_security_group_ids
    )

    for security_group in security_groups["SecurityGroups"]:
        for ingress_rule in security_group["IpPermissions"]:
            print(ingress_rule)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output**

```
{'FromPort': 22, 'IpProtocol': 'tcp', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0', 'Description': 'SSH'}], 'Ipv6Ranges': [{'CidrIpv6': '::/0', 'Description': 'SSH'}], 'PrefixListIds': [], 'ToPort': 22, 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}
{'IpProtocol': '-1', 'IpRanges': [], 'Ipv6Ranges': [], 'PrefixListIds': [], 'UserIdGroupPairs': [{'GroupId': 'sg-04dfdddc2792af7e2', 'UserId': '12312313123'}]}
{'FromPort': 80, 'IpProtocol': 'tcp', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}], 'Ipv6Ranges': [{'CidrIpv6': '::/0'}], 'PrefixListIds': [], 'ToPort': 80, 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}
{'FromPort': 5432, 'IpProtocol': 'tcp', 'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}], 'Ipv6Ranges': [{'CidrIpv6': '::/0'}], 'PrefixListIds': [], 'ToPort': 5432, 'UserIdGroupPairs': []}
```

Instead of printing the rules, you can do any processing with them that you like.
Of course translating security group ids to IP-Ranges is a whole different problem, but given your question I assume your security groups only contain IP ranges.

Comment: Thanks Maurice. The problem is there are some security groups as well with some ip ranges. So translating them is a problem.

Comment: Well, then you need to add the CIDR range of the VPC, the security groups belongs to, to your list. In principle these security groups can be applied to instances in the whole VPC. Also security group IDs may belong to other AWS accounts if they're connected through Peering or a Transit Gateway in the same region.